# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied jruby error on mkdir

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, jruby, mkdir

I am having ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am using rvm and ruby. 
rvm list gives following output:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/rujoota/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use jruby-1.7.19'.

rvm rubies

=* jruby-1.7.19 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

 => - current

 =* - current && default

 *- default
```

I tried everything but the warning still appears.

When I am trying to run my ruby application, I get the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /myfolder
mkdir at org/jruby/RubyDir.java:452
fu_mkdir at /home/myhome/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:247
mkdir_p at /home/myhome/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:221
reverse_each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1693
mkdir_p at /home/myhome/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:219
each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
mkdir_p at /home/myhome/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:205
initialize at /home/myhome/myfolder/myproject
```

I have full access on myfolder and .rvm. Still facing this issue, can someone help me?

Comment: try jruby 1.7.22 ... might be a bug if it works under MRI